# Do I need the 18-55mm lens that comes with the camera, or should I instead get a 55-250mm lens?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, focal-length, lens-recommendation

I'm a novice so don't know whether I need the 18-55mm lens that comes standard with the Canon EOS Rebel T6i or should I instead get the 55-250 mm lens - or both?  I'll be using the camera primarily for family photos during holidays and vacations - both indoors and outdoors.  On occasion will take longer shots at sporting events and on trips out west.

Comment: check out the 18-135mm stm lens instead of the 18-55mm. It is more expensive but you won't have to switch your lens as much. I also have the 55-250mm stm lens for outdoors.

Comment: Look at the "super zooms" offered by 3rd party vendors. Compare the results on a good technical photo site such as DxO optics which provides visual displays of relative performance at a wide range of lens settings (aperture/focal length). This helps you decide  whether the $/quality tradeoff is acceptable. You can get eg Sigma & Tamron lenses in the 17 or 18mm to 250 to 300mm range. Results are vastly better than for the super-zooms of a decade ago which gave these lenses such a bad name. You are liable to be delighted with the results in many cases.

Answer (score 6):

Get both.

You will definitely need the 18-55mm lens for shooting indoors and general all around photography as it covers wide-angle to short telephoto. The 55-250mm is a great lens for wildlife or sporting events, but it is much too long for shooting indoors.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 18-135 option like what Rob had mentioned above. When I got my first DSLR, I just had an 18-55 and it would really irritate me at times as it has a very short range of zoom. Also, if you have two lenses, 18-55 & 55-250, you will have to switch between the two quite often and that could a) irritate you as a beginner, and b) more importantly expose your camera and lens to dust!

If you have a budget constraint, have a look at Tamron 18-135. Quite worth the money!